# Can I define another Set in Agda

Tags: types, agda, dependent-type

By this I mean can I do something that behaves something like

```
NewSet : Set1
```

and then go on to do things like

```
data \bot : NewSet where
```

Comment: `NewSet = Set`, `NewSet = ℕ -> Set`. Why do you need this?

Comment: Mostly because I'm uncomfortable with having logical propositions having the same type as things like the natural number. I don't know if my fear is reasonable, but I wanted to know if I could make a new class of types

Comment: What is a logical proposition? [Types are theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence). Agda has [irrelevance](http://wiki.portal.chalmers.se/agda/pmwiki.php?n=ReferenceManual.Irrelevance) for something "purely logical", but doesn't have an impredicative universe like `Prop` in Coq.

Comment: I don't know type theory, but can you explain what something like the natural numbers means with respect to the curry-howard correspondence. I guess I'm still skeptical that if I define a Logical AND type, that i get a meaningful answer when I put in a natural number. Also, I'm new to Agda and wondered whether I could "copy" Set if you will. Is your first comment supposed to be an answer? I don't think it behaves the same way as Set

Comment: "what something like the natural numbers means with respect to the curry-howard correspondence" — that there is at least one natural number. Not very useful, but the Curry–Howard correspondence works better in the other direction — from proofs to programs. Your logical AND is just the type constructor that makes tuples. `NewSet = Set` not only behaves like `Set` — it's indistinguishable from `Set`: you can use `NewSet` anywhere instead of `Set`. So it's not a copy — just another name.

Comment: A small remark: `NewSet` is indistinguishable from `Set` if `Set` means `Set₀`. `Set` is overloaded and can be a function that receives a `Level`. `NewSet` can't be a function.

Comment: You say `can you explain what something like the natural numbers means with respect to the curry-howard correspondence`, but just as in imperative programming it's not true that all types are number types, likewise in agda, not all types are interesting theorem types.